# Org.springframework.web.servlet.dispatcherservlet nohandler found no mapping found

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, controller

I know that this question has been a many times, and i tried a lot, but it doesn't work. I have some errors and i don't know exactly what to do with them. The server looks like is not recognizing the css files and the javascript files that are define in the jsp files.

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" id="WebApp_ID"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<display-name>spring-mvc-crud-demo</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>Index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-crud-demo-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

<!-- Add support for component scanning -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.controller" />

<!-- Add support for conversion, formatting and validation support -->
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WebContent/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

Controller

```
package com.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value= "/intent", method= RequestMethod.POST)
public class IntentController {

@RequestMapping("/notepad")
public String Notepad(){

    System.out.println("Notepad is redy");
    return "Index";
}
```

The error
The server does not see the css files and the javascript.

```
Sep 21, 2017 11:32:06 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/ApiAi/assets/css/noscript.css] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
Sep 21, 2017 11:32:06 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/ApiAi/assets/js/jquery.min.js] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
Sep 21, 2017 11:32:06 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/ApiAi/assets/css/mainCss.css] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
Sep 21, 2017 11:32:06 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/ApiAi/assets/js/skel.min.js] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
Sep 21, 2017 11:32:06 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/ApiAi/assets/js/util.js] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
Sep 21, 2017 11:32:06 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/ApiAi/assets/js/main.js] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
Sep 21, 2017 11:32:06 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/ApiAi/images/pic03.jpg] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Project structure would have been helpful to give exact answer.
Though this may not be working because you have not provided the resource mapping in your servlet.xml file. Try again by providing proper resource path mapping using the following tag

```
 <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/<your_path>" />
```

Comment: Yes this was the problem, and I didn't have the css files in the resources folder